# Sub menu of dropdown menu pushing ul li

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

here is what's happening.

As required!

http://jsfiddle.net/U99Br/

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q466a.png]

So I'm making this web site with a drop down menu, until now it was all good, but while doing my drop-down menu (I wanted to do something of the sort of Netflix's menu), I noticed my sub-menu is pushing the "contact" `li` tag `300px` away (which is it's length).

Here's my code:

```
#menu,
#menu ul,
#menu li {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 }

#menu a {
 text-decoration: none;
  }

#menu {
 height: 60px;
 width: auto;
  }

#menu > ul > li {
 float: left;
 margin-left: 15px;
 position: relative;
  }

#menu > ul > li > a {
 color: #fff;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #737373;
 font-size: 20px;
 line-height: 60px;
 padding: 15px 20px;
  }

#menu > ul > li > a:hover {
 color: #000;
  }

#menu > ul > li > ul {
 opacity: 0;
 visibility: hidden;
 display: none;
 background-color: #fff;
 text-align: left;
 height: auto;
 box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 width: 300px;
  }

#menu > ul > li:hover > ul {
 display: block;
 border: none;
 visibility: visible;
 opacity: 1;
  }

#menu > ul > li > ul > li {
 display: block;
 content: '';
  }

#menu > ul > li > ul > li > a {
 font-size: 12px;
 color: #000;
 display: block;
 text-shadow: none;
  }

#menu > ul > li > ul > li > a:hover {
 color: #0AB3FC;
  }

#menu > ul ul > li {
  position: relative;
}
```

I have not found what's wrong in my coding yet!

Comment: Providing HTML source will be much better than a screenshot.

Comment: Yes, please provide HTML content or use jsfiddle.com to provide a working example

Answer (score 2):

ad a width to the first ul li so children can not push up width from parent

```
#menu > ul > li {
   width:300px; /* add with here */
   float: left;
   margin-left: 15px;
   position: relative;
}
```

Comment: @AxelPuyo you're welcome, glad I could help. could you please accept the answer as the right one?